# Default Content for Empty Datagrid or Listbox in WPF

Tags: wpf, listbox, default, wpfdatagrid, empty-list

Does anyone know how to add default content to an empty datagrid or listbox? Such as "No Results Returned" or something along those lines.

Comment: Does "No Results Returned" actually need to be part of this list? You can easily just have a trigger that will show this message whenever the list is empty..

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do. I think I have found out how to do this. I will post once tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, where the `ListBox` is Hidden and an associated error `Grid` is displayed instead. The benefit of this approach is that it is a bit more flexible, as you have an entire `Grid` to use instead of a `VisualBrush`.

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox">
        <ListBox.Style>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            <Style TargetType="ListBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Style>
    </ListBox>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=Items.Count}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        <Grid.Style>
        <TextBlock Text="No Results Returned" />
    </Grid>
<Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have multiple listboxes on a single layout and I don't use a Grid. I have my layout arranged in StackPanels. I just find this easier for some reason. So I needed it within the ListBox contents without adding an actual ListBoxItem. This way each ListBox can be placed/templated into user controls for repeated use.  Thank you for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" Value="False" />
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                        <TextBlock Text="We did't find any matching records for your group..." FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="LightCoral"/>
                                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                </VisualBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
```

This is what I have found and was able to to test it. Thanks to anyone who tried to help.